Identify SMD crystal marked EATC
Can everybody help me to identify crystal EATC such as picture below?


The EPSON MC-146 TYPE Brief Sheet has a picture which looks to the same style of package and with a marking of EA99. So far haven't found a crystal with the marking of EATC. To help get an answer can you (a) measure the dimensions of the crystal (b) give a bigger picture of the board to identify which nearby device the crystal is likely to be connected to as that might help to identify the crystal frequency.

This is MC-146 32.768KHz ±20PPM (7.0 * 1.5 * 1.4)mm resonator from Epson

How can we distinguish between Mc-146 and MC 146- Type?
